# JSONObject in Scala

Tags: json, scala

I'm very new to Scala and I'm trying to send a json from a client to a service.
I have an interface ("trait") where I have the method receiveData takes a JSONObject as an argument, but apparently it's deprecated.

```
trait DataService {
 def receiveData(data: JSONObject, clientId: String): Unit
}
```

I have this Scala version ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "3.0.0-RC1"

I have looked around for what I should use instead and found nothing.
it says

```
 @deprecated("Use The Scala Library Index to find alternatives: https://index.scala-lang.org/", "1.0.6")
```

but I don't know how to search for things there.

Appreciate all help!

***EDIT:***

**ANSWER**:  there are plenty: Play-Json, zio-json, Circe, Jackson...

Comment: `JSONObject` is not part of Scala standard library. Can you tell us from where it comes from? You probably have an `import` at the top of your code giving you a hint.

Comment: it's `import scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject`

Comment: Ah right my bad. It was indeed part of Scala in quite old versions. So you need to find out a library to handle JSON, there are plenty: Play-Json, zio-json, Circe, Jackson... Pick the one you prefer.

Comment: Well you could have just read the error which points to **Scaladex** where there is a button to search for **JSOBN** libraries for **Scala**: https://index.scala-lang.org/search?q=*&topics=json - Check their readmes and pick one whose usage feels natural to you, you may also search for blog post comparing them, or just ask in the **Discord** server for recommendations